# Trying to query Parent using child and another parent matching Parent --> Child --> Parent

Tags: soql, lookup, list, master-detail

I have 3 objects.

Event, Invite & Attendee

Event  - > Invite  (one Event to Many Invites) Master Detail relationship
Invite has event details

Attendee  - > Invite  (one Attendee to Many Invites) Master Detail relationship
Invite has Attendee details

Now I want to fetch Attendee from Invites which belong to a particular meeting i.e, fetch Attendee details from Meeting details.

Parent --> Child --> Parent

Is this possible. Please Help.

I used the following Query. It is fetching me all the Attendees irrespective of the meeting.

```
List<Attendee__c> attns = [select id,name,Attendee_Email__c,Country__c ,(select id,name,Request_Status__c from Invites__r where Meeting__r.name=:meetName) from Attendee__c];
```

Please help .

Thank you.

Comment: you can create 2 queries and try to match those considering invitees in a map

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Event fetch Invitees.

```
Map<Id, Invites__c> inviteeMap = new Map<Id,Invites__c>([SELECT Id, Name, Request_Status__c 
                                                        FROM Invites__c 
                                                        WHERE Invites__r.EventId =:EventId]);
```

Now, based on the Invitees, retrieve Attendees.

```
List<Invites__c> lstInvitee =   [SELECT Attendee__r.id, 
                                        Attendee__r.name,
                                        Attendee__r.Attendee_Email__c,
                                        Attendee__r.Country__c 
                                        FROM Invites__c 
                                        WHERE Id IN:inviteeMap.keySet()];
```

Comment: Thank you . But after this also we are fetching list of Invites only. I want to get Attendee objects and use them for update, edit etc. Can this be acheived using the attendee fields in the fetched invite?

Comment: Like to change attendee name, if I change Attendee__r.name field in the Invite, will it work? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What @Santanu Boral has told in comments is a good way to do it. Have 2 queries and then match using apex.

However, if you HAVE to use a single query for this, you can do the below:

```
List<Attendee__c> attns = new List<Attendee__c>();
for(Invite__c inv : [select Id, Attenee__c, Attenee__r.Name, Attenee__r.Attendee_Email__c, Attenee__r.Country__c from Invite__c where Meeting__r.name=:meetName])
{
    Attendee__c att = new Attendee__c();
    att.Id = inv.Attenee__c;
    att.Name = inv.Attenee__r.Name;
    att.Attendee_Email__c = inv.Attenee__r.Attendee_Email__c;
    attns.add(att);
}
```

You have your list of Attendees in `attns`

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to fetch Attendee from Invites which belong to a particular Meeting :

```
List<Meeting__c> meetList = new List<Meeting__c>([Select name from Meeting__c]);
List<string> meetName = new List<string>();

for(Meeting__c obj:meetList){
    meetName.add(obj.name);
}

List<Attendee__c> attns = new List<Attendee__c>();
attns = [Select id, name, Attendee_Email__c, Country__c from Attendee__c  where ID IN (Select Attendee_lk__c from Invites__c where Meeting__r.name=:meetName)];
```

Comment: Used this. 

attns = [Select id,name,Attendee_Email__c,Country__c from Attendee__c 
                    where ID IN (Select Attendee_lk__c from Invite__c where Meeting__r.name=:meetName)];

It is not fetching any results

Comment: Getting an empty list

Comment: @Paps Check edited answer. Let me know if any query.